# Timeout expired after a brute force login attack

Tags: sql-server-2008, timeout

This morning, I navigated to my website and saw it crashed with this message after any stored procedure:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I noticed in the Event Viewer that there has been a brute force login attack by someone trying to use 'sa', so I disabled remote access.

Appart from that, I have no clue about what happened. Now, no ASP.Net page can be processed because SQL Server 2008 requests don't work and always return Timeout when trying to execute a stored procedures.

What could be the cause, and what should I check and fix?

[EDIT 3]

Resolved by changing the IP in the connection string to 127.0.0.1. An obscure firewall setting was still blocking external IP after I blocked then unblocked access to SQL port from external IPs.

[EDIT 2]

I made a query directly in SQL and the message shown is:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server.
```

[EDIT]

Three possibilities are listed in a similar thread:

1 - There's a deadlock somewhere.

No, because:

- All stored procedures now answer with this error
- No code or procedure has been changed after the attack.

2 - The database's statistics and/or query plan cache are incorrect

I typed DBCC FREEPROCCACHE, it successfully deleted the cache with no errors.

I typed exec sp_updatestats, cache reset didn't change anything.

3 - The query is too complex and needs to be tuned

Same as 1. And stored procedures are very simple / basic.

Comment: This question was once asked here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers for this question (I mean "in other threads", not "here") should also have focussed on the essential:

**This error can also mean that it's impossible to communicate with SQL Server using the current connection string**. Very basic.

In my case, my Windows firewall didn't (as usual) reflect how it was really acting. When was under brute force attack, I blocked access to SQL ports in the firewall and rebooted (and it changed nothing). Then after a while, even after I deleted this rule, it seems SQL began to refuse access to any IP address appart from lan IPs. But I wasn't thinking anymore about this rule in the firewall anymore. Anyway, I wanted to block external access and figured out after that there was a 'case' to check in SQL Manager to do this.

What I've done is to **change my public IP address to 127.0.0.1 in the connection string**.