# Occasionally Getting SqlException: Timeout expired

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2012

I have application running on my server. The problem with this application is that daily I am getting nearly 10-20, `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding` only one of my SP. Here is my SP,

```
            ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insertorupdatedevicecatalog] 
                            (@OS                NVARCHAR(50) 
                            ,@UniqueID          VARCHAR(500)
                            ,@Longitude         FLOAT 
                            ,@Latitude          FLOAT
                            ,@Culture           VARCHAR(10)
                            ,@Other             NVARCHAR(200)
                            ,@IPAddress         VARCHAR(50)
                            ,@NativeDeviceID    VARCHAR(50))
            AS 
            BEGIN 

                DECLARE @OldUniqueID VARCHAR(500) = '-1';
                SELECT @OldUniqueID = [UniqueID] FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE (@NativeDeviceID != '' AND [NativeDeviceID] = @NativeDeviceID);

                BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
                    BEGIN TRY
                        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE [UniqueID] = @UniqueID) 
                        BEGIN 
                            UPDATE  DeviceCatalog 
                               SET  [OS] = @OS
                                   ,[Location] = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100 ), @Longitude) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @Latitude) + ')', 4326)
                                   ,[Culture] = @Culture
                                   ,[Other] = @Other
                                   ,[Lastmodifieddate] = Getdate()
                                   ,[IPAddress] = @IPAddress
                            WHERE   [UniqueID] = @UniqueID;
                        END
                        ELSE 
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO DeviceCatalog
                                        ([OS]
                                        ,[UniqueID]
                                        ,[Location] 
                                        ,[Culture] 
                                        ,[Other]
                                        ,[IPAddress]
                                        ,[NativeDeviceID])
                                VALUES  (@OS
                                        ,@UniqueID
                                        ,geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100) ,@Longitude) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @Latitude) + ')', 4326) 
                                        ,@Culture
                                        ,@Other
                                        ,@IPAddress
                                        ,@NativeDeviceID);
                                IF(@OldUniqueID != '-1' AND @OldUniqueID != @UniqueID)
                                BEGIN
                                    EXEC DeleteOldDevice @OldUniqueID, @UniqueID;
                                END
                        END
                        COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1];
                    END TRY
                    BEGIN CATCH
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1];
                        DECLARE @ErrorNumber nchar(5), @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048);
                        SELECT
                            @ErrorNumber = RIGHT('00000' + ERROR_NUMBER(), 5),
                            @ErrorMessage = @ErrorNumber + ' ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
                        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16, 1);
                    END CATCH
            END
```

Is there is any issue with this SP? Why I am getting Timeout exception only in this SP? Here is the Stack Trace,

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at App.Classes.DBLayer.Execute(SqlCommand command, Boolean executeNonQuery)
   at App.Helpers.SQLHelper.GetResult(List`1 parameters, Boolean storedProcedure, String commandText, ResultType type)
   at App.Helpers.SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(List`1 parameters, Boolean storedProcedure, String commandText)
   at App.Services.DeviceCatalogService.InsertOrUpdateDeviceCatalog(DeviceCatalog deviceCataLog)
   at WebApplication1.Handlers.RegisterDevice.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Why? Because execution took too long. Optimize it. Impossible to answer this question with the details provided. Voting to close.

Comment: did you get solution using ***https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx*** `CommandTimeout` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to investigate this on the server side to understand why is the execution timing out. Note that the server has no timeout, the timeout is caused by the default 30 seconds on [`SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx).

A good resource is [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx), which is a methodology to diagnose performance bottlenecks with SQL Server. Based on the actual cause of the timeout, proper action can be taken. You must establish first and foremost whether you're dealing with slow execution (a bad plan) or blocking.

If I'd venture a guess, I would say that the unhealthy pattern of `IF EXISTS... UPDATE` is the root cause. This pattern is incorrect and will cause failures under concurrency. Two concurrent transaction executing the `IF EXISTS` simultaneously will both reach the same conclusion and *both* attempt to `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. Depending on the exiting constraints in the database you can end up with a deadlock (the lucky case) or with a lost write (the unlucky case). However, only proper investigation would reveal the actual root cause. Could be something totally different, like [auto-growth events](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/).

Your procedure is also incorrectly handling the CATCH block. You must **always** check the [`XACT_STATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx) because the transaction may be already rolled back by the time your CATCH block runs. Is also not clear what you expect from naming the transaction, this is a common mistake I see often associated with confusing named transactions with savepoints. For a correct pattern see [Exception Handling and Nested Transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/).

**Edit**

Here is a possible way to investigate this:

1. Change the relevant [`CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) to 0 (ie. infinite).
2. Enable the [`blocked process threshold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181150.aspx), set it to 30 seconds (the former CommandTimeout)
3. Monitor in Profiler for [Blocked Process Report Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191168.aspx)
4. Start your workload
5. See if the Profiler produces any report events. If it does, they will pinpoint the cause.

These actions will cause a 'blocked process report' event every time you would had get a timeout, if the timeout was cause by blocking. You application will continue to wait until the blocking is removed, if the blocking is caused by a [live-lock](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/the-problem-with-logging.html) then it will wait forever.

Comment: The slow part of the query could be in any part. The root cause could be anything. I consider the question to be unanswerable. +1

Comment: @usr, I have lot of extensive and big queries that does not throw this error, only this SQL. I believe there is something wrong in this SP. I think the execution is inserting or updating nothing special. There is no indexing in database and the table include only 800 records. What else inf you need?

Comment: `IF EXISTS ... UPDATE` alternative: [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). You must have a (clustered?) index on `[UniqueID]` (yes, even at `VARCHAR(500)`).

Comment: Also, checkout this about [how to use `sp_whoisactive`](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/)

Comment: @RemusRusanu done see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039925/danger-of-using-if-exists-update-else-insert-and-what-is-the-alternat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation

Answer (score 10):

Add this line to your connection string:

```
Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200
```

You can set `myCom.CommandTimeout = 200` also

If large number of data is there you can also increase the timeout seconds from 200 to 600 seconds.

Edit this in web.config as well.

Follow [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) doccument.

Comment: I think he's saying that the procedure taking too long is the problem, and increasing the timeout isn't really addressing the problem.

Comment: Increasing the timeout can be a valid solution, especially considering that the OP is obviously not an expert at query tuning. It is an obvious solution however.

Comment: although its obvious solution, i think, OP has not tried it. Because after that i dont think so he would have posted this issue.

Comment: No this one also takes milliseconds in normal condition.

Answer (score 1):

This can happens because of parameter sniffing. So just use local variables, declared within the stored proc. and use them appropriately.

Declare @InVar1 ...

.....

where condition=@Invar1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the **OPTIMIZE FOR** or **WITH RECOMPILE** hints solve the SQL Exception Timeout problem.

This article teachs how to implement it  and explains the "parameter sniffing" issues:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/