# Converting Traditional IF EXIST UPDATE ELSE INSERT into MERGE is not working?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am going to use MERGE to insert or update a table depending upon ehether it's exist or not. This is my query,

```
declare @t table
(
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
)
insert into @t values(1,'a')

MERGE INTO @t t1
USING (SELECT id FROM @t WHERE ID = 2) t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET name = 'd', id = 3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name)
    VALUES (2, 'b');

select * from @t;
```

The result is,

```
id  name
1   a
```

I think it should be,

```
id  name
1   a
2   b
```

Comment: @MAri what do you mean?

Comment: For each DML operations you have to commit the transaction. Then only you will be able to see the latest data..

Comment: @Mari I don't have any transaction

Comment: Why do you want to switch to `MERGE` for such a simple case? [Thar be dragons](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44069/1186), IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, see this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039925/danger-of-using-if-exists-update-else-insert-and-what-is-the-alternat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mikhail pointed out, your query in the `USING` clause doesn't contain any rows.

If you want to do an upsert, put the new data into the `USING` clause:

```
MERGE INTO @t t1
USING (SELECT 2 as id, 'b' as name) t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) --This no longer has an artificial dependency on @t
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET name = t2.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name)
    VALUES (t2.id, t2.name);
```

Comment: Damien, I need a general solution. Actually I want to convert my traditional if not exist insert else update with Merge

Comment: @user960567 - I'm not sure what you mean by a "general solution" - what I've posted is the general way to do this. You put the *source* data in the `USING` clause - whether it be literals, as shown above, or it's a query against some other table. If you want a better answer, please provide some actual sample data and expected results. The query I've shown does produce the result that you've asked for.

Comment: Just 1 single question damien? Is there any benefit of putting the above statement in transaction(normally)?

Comment: @user960567 - every DML statement runs inside a transaction - whether you explicitly open one or not. If you don't open one, SQL Server opens one automatically and, by default, will commit it if the statement completes without error. There's an alternative mode (called Implicit Transactions) where it will instead leave the transaction open when the statement completes, but that's not on by default. So if you just planned to surround the above code with a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and a `COMMIT`, I'd say no - because SQL Server is already doing exactly that.

Comment: Besides, if you're really inserting into a `@table variable`, there isn't a whole lot of meaning to your transaction...

Comment: AaronBertrand, Actually @table was demo. I am doing this in my physical tables. Thanks Damien

Answer (score 3):

You have your `USING` part slightly messed up, that's where to put what you want to match against (although in this case you're only using `id`)

```
declare @t table
(
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
)

insert into @t values(1,'a')

MERGE INTO @t t1
USING (SELECT 2, 'b') AS t2 (id, name) ON (t1.id = t2.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET name = 'd', id = 3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name)
    VALUES (2, 'b');

select * from @t;
```

Comment: Jaochim, I need a general solution. Actually I want to convert my traditional if not exist insert else update with Merge

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, you'll need to add more detail to your question for that to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

This query won't return anything:

```
SELECT id FROM @t WHERE ID = 2
```

Because where is no rows in table with ID = 2, so there is nothing to merge into table.

---

Besides, in MATCHED clause you are updating a field ID on which you are joining table, i think, it's forbidden.

Comment: I need solution. I need to insert if not exist and update when exist

Answer (score 0):

For each DML operations you have to commit (Marks the end of a successful the transaction)Then only you will be able to see the latest data

For example :

```
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO
DELETE FROM HumanResources.JobCandidate
    WHERE JobCandidateID = 13;
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Comment: Same result. Please this yourself before posting