# SQL probably leaking connections even though I'm calling Connection.Close()

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a thread (called through `new Thread(new ThreadStart(...))`) that is always running while my software is running that makes a polling in a database.

In a very simplyfied way, it basically does the following:

```
void Polling()
{
    Thread.Sleep(500); 
    methodA();
    if (certainTimePassed)
        methodB();
    if (anotherCertainTimePassed)
        methodC();
    ...
}

void methodA()
{
    SIDataContext db = new SIDataContext(_host.Config.ConnectionString);
    if (looksForSomeData())
        raiseSomeEvents();
    db.Connection.Close();
}
```

It runs by hours and hours fine. However, **if I stress the application by making the looksForSomeData() returning always true (i.e. constantly inserting the data it searches) AND at the same time use another software part that query large SELECTs at the database**, it eventually produces the following (always in MethodA, probably because it's the one is most called):

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I think it may be some more complex problem. But since I have only a few months experience with LINQs DataContext() I'm not sure.

Things to note/I tried:

- Using `using` instead of `db.Connection.Close()`
- There is no way that it is opening the connection, raising an exception, and not closing the connection, because if an exception is raised in this thread the software quits
- The events raised in `raiseSomeEvents()` does not accumulate (probably), because there is some kind of semaphore solution that makes an event raised only it is not already running.
- Catching the exception and doing nothing. The software slows down and even froze for some moments and then comes back to normal (seems the connections are eventually released).

**I appreciate anything that could help me diagnose where the problem could be.**

Comment: Are you sure that the connections are being leaked, or that you're asking for a connection while the pool is full?  This can happen if the time it takes for you to close a connection takes long.

Comment: I'm not sure they are leaked, I just supposed because of the exception, so that is a possibility, I will investigate.

Comment: Is it possible that sometimes exceptions are thrown and caught?your code does not close the connection if an exception happens (hint: use "using")

Comment: @MarcGravell I've checked that. Actually I was using `using` before, and changed to the explicit Connection.Close() to try to solve the problem.

Comment: When this happens, is there any blocking at the db?

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry, what exactly you mean by blocking?

Comment: @AndréSantaló database blocking; sp_who2 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just connection pooling.  It's very expensive to initiate a new connection, so .Net will keep the connections open and re-use them.

Comment: Even if I'm constantly calling Connection.Close()?

Comment: That's correct.  Connection pooling will not close the underlying connection.

Comment: That's interesting. I think I have little knowledge about connection pooling, I will read about it.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer because the problem was exaclty that... the connection pool was growing larger and larger the more my thread run. I discovered this through debugging and running sp_who2.

Comment: @AndréSantaló, please make your own answer instead of [modifying another's](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3438192).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have indexes on your tables? The large number of inserts would also cause the indexes to be updated which could adversely affect your select statements. Also the select statements may also be using the temp database to ensure that they are repeatable, again something that could be expensive. These may have a cumulative affect that is pushing up the time needed to complete what was a fast operation

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your query is taking an abnormal amount of time to run (i.e. greater than 10-15 seconds). In these cases the connection can time out. I would reccommend that you try running the query by itself, using any parameters that may be passed by the application, and if it is taking a long time to query, see if there is any way that you can improve the SQL.

You can always reference this: [Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `methodA()`, and tell me what you think will happen if an exception is thrown or the thread is aborted after creating the data context, but before closing it? The correct answer is that the connection will be left hanging open, at least of a while.

You **must** encase anything to do with database access in a `try`/`finally` block, such that the connection is closed as part of the `finally`. The easiest way to do this is with a `using` block. I know you said you tried that, but you should have posted that code:

```
void methodA()
{
    using (SIDataContext db = new SIDataContext(_host.Config.ConnectionString))
    {
        if (looksForSomeData())
            raiseSomeEvents();
    }
}
```