# Extending query time out period

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, .net-3.0

I have the following code, which "sometimes" gives a timeout error

```
string select = @"query goes here";
connection1 = new SqlConnection("connection string goes ehre");
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, connection1);
SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

The error message is:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding.

How do I extend the timeout period?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the command timeout.

From your example you just have to do:

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60;
```