# Why do i get the following error, when i try to click a asp.net button using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

**ERROR:**

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

**FYR - check the below error screenshot**[image]

*Please help.*

Comment: You need to provide more information about the error.
What happened before the error occurs?
Which environment do you use?

Comment: try to execute same query on sql-server.see if it executes

Comment: I suspect the issue is database related, so you must provide the code and highlight the line where this error is occurring,or  ( set `CommandTimeout = 0;`) in the command object

Comment: Actually I'm trying to click a button from vb.net program.This error comes once it interacts with the function inside the button click event. And that function is to call an Stored Procedure which doesn't return a value. Hence, it loads & shows the above error.
Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you need to turn off customerrors to get a better idea of what is going on.

```
    <system.web> 
<customErrors mode="Off">
 </customErrors>
```

This type of timeout usually is from issues with SQL:

1. There's a deadlock somewhere
2. The database's statistics and/or query plan cache are incorrect
3. The query is too complex and needs to be tuned

The second issue will cause the database to use a sub-optimal query plan. It can be resolved by clearing the statistics:

```
exec sp_updatestats
```

If that doesn't work you could also try

```
dbcc freeproccache
```

A good reference to the same issue that you are having can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation)