# Adding Command Timeout in .Net Aspx Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got the .aspx page which is simply using SQL query and grid to show the result in the page. I don't have code behind, it is just the aspx page.
How can I add command timeout in aspx page or web.config? In web.config I know I can add Connection timeout in connection string as Connection Timeout=1000, but how can I add command timeout so that I don't get Timeout Expired message while selecting the dropdown parameter to open the page. It seems like my query is taking long time to run and I need to increase command timeout.

**Timeout message I am getting:**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
> the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout
> expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding.
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period
> elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
> responding.]
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection) +212
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj) +245    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
> runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj) +1099
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +58
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +112
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6319508
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> async) +6320577
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, DbAsyncResult result) +424
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method) +28
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method) +211
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior) +19
> System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior) +19    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
> dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
> String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +221
> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
> startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
> CommandBehavior behavior) +573
> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
> srcTable) +161
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
> arguments) +2803174
> System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
> arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +27
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +261
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +46
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +3394

Comment: Can you show us the exact timeout message?

Comment: I have added the exact timeout message I am getting in the question I have asked.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
command.CommandTimeout = 600; This needs to be added to codebehind if any right? In my case there is no code behind, it's just aspx page with grid. Isn't it same like how I am already adding in web.config?

Comment: If you have a connection string in your Web.config, you can add `Timeout=600;` or `Connect Timeout=600;` to it (not sure which one is good, I see both in various places).

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the executionTimeout in Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" ... />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The value is expressed in seconds.

**UPDATE**

According to your exception message, one solution would be to increase the timeout of the SQLCommand object:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
command.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

Other suggestions for a similar problem are given here: [Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation)

Comment: I added <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000"/> in web.config and restarted the IIS. Still timeout happening. In SQL server side it's just taking 9 sec to run the query. Other dropdown parameter selection works with less data, but only one of the selection doesn't work and shows timeout expired message. I also made <compilation debug="false" >