# Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: c#, sql, sqldataadapter

When I run my code I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

My code is the following:

```
    private void FillInDataGrid(string SQLstring)
    {
        string cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Scratchpad"].ConnectionString; //hier wordt de databasestring opgehaald
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(cn);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLstring, myConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        myConnection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
        myConnection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
    }
```

And my SQLstring is the following:

```
SELECT dbo.[new].[colom1],dbo.[new].[colom2],dbo.[new].[colom3],dbo.[new].[colom4],  
                dbo.[new].[Value] as 'nieuwe Value',
                dbo.[old].[Value] as 'oude Value'
                FROM dbo.[new]
                JOIN dbo.[old] ON dbo.[new].[colom1] = dbo.[old].[colom1] and dbo.[new].[colom2] = dbo.[old].[colom2] and dbo.[new].[colom3] = dbo.[old].[colom3] and dbo.[new].[colom4] = dbo.[old].[colom4] 
                where dbo.[new].[Value] <> dbo.[old].[Value]
```

Comment: your query seems to be taking time executing

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Do you think the time executing is the problem here?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I `only` got a table of around 7000rows

Comment: connection string is wrong then

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I am connecting to that same string earlier, and that works

Comment: Clearly there is a timeout during execution. May be the number of rows, the joins, the conditions you have in the joins. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation?rq=1

Comment: @EhsanSajjad and bit You guys were indeed right, I made the table even smaller, and now it executed

Comment: Is there a specific requirement where you're needing to check equality between every single column of both tables in your JOIN section?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  I think the question is not duplicate. One is for [sql Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlcommand) And another is for [SqlDataAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqldataadapter) . As both are from System.Data.SqlClient namespace so the error message is same.  But solution way is different.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman setting the query timeout is same in either case

Comment: @EhsanSajjad one is   
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, dbCon);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300; and another is 
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandTimeout = 300;

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your query needs more than the default 30 seconds, you might want to set the [CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) higher. To do that you'll change it after you instantiated the DataAdapter on the SelectCommand property of that instance, like so:

```
private void FillInDataGrid(string SQLstring)
{
    string cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Scratchpad"].ConnectionString; //hier wordt de databasestring opgehaald
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // dispose objects that implement IDisposable
    using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(cn))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLstring, myConnection);

        // set the CommandTimeout
        dataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60;  // seconds

        myConnection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table"); 
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
}
```

The other option is to address your query. In Sql Server you can analyze the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan). I bet there is a full-table scan in it. You might experiment with adding an index on one or two columns in your `[old]` and `[new]` table. Keep in mind that adding indexes comes at the cost of higher execution times for inserts and updates and space requirements.

Comment: I tried 60 seconds, but it still didnt load, im going to try 15minutes now, is there any way to let the process speed up? besides changing my cpu.

Comment: As I said, your query is the problem. You might try adding indexes. And I would simply run that statement in Sql Server management studio and optimize there based on the outcome of the execution plan.

Comment: After an hour it still wasnt done :P I am now executing the query in de SQL server management studio which already takes 5mins haha