# How can I compare a number which was saved as a string in a database to an integer field?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have tried this line of code but it ran into an error

```
CMR cmr = _cmrServices.GetAllWithAll().Where(x => x.CMRSerial == cmrSearchDeliverySerialNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```

```
Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Inner Exception 2:
Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
```

I couldn't change the type of my fields to integer in the database also neither can compare my value to the string of a number because it gets a timeout error.

[image]
but as you can see they are numeric with string type.
[image]

this field `cmrSearchDeliverySerialNumber` is string though ,no matter what type it is I can't filter `CMRSerial` field as an integer.

I dont know should I use  SqlFunctions.StringConvert or somthing else to convert CMRSerial` to an integer.

unfortunately I cant set index on `CMRSerial` field due its type is `nvarchar(max)` and I can't compare it as string to another string.

I ran this line of codes after executin my query that was created by profiler

```
SELECT QP.query_plan as [Query Plan], 
       ST.text AS [Query Text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS R
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(R.plan_handle) AS QP
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(R.plan_handle) ST;
```

[image]

Comment: This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation

Comment: Put an index on CMRSerial

Comment: @JamesBlackburn my problem is not the timeout. it is converting

Comment: You are doing an implicit convertion, this is really bad in terms of performance. I would recommand to do an explicit cast/convert and then comapre it. As a rule of thumb, if it looks like integer but isn't and you want to compare it, cast it first (but say goodby to any index on that column)

Comment: @GertArnold I just asked about converting a string field to an integer in linq.

Comment: Also, it would help to know details of your environment:, mainly Entity Framework (?) version, mapping details.

Comment: @GertArnold I use version 6.0.0.0 Entity Framework

Comment: Mapping info? What matters most is if the property is mapped as unicode.

Comment: Please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. You can get it via SQL Profiler, Extended Events or Query Store (profiler is prob easiest)

Comment: @Charlieface How can see my query plan ?is it correct?```SELECT QP.query_plan as [Query Plan], 
       ST.text AS [Query Text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS R
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(R.plan_handle) AS QP
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(R.plan_handle) ST;```

Comment: Yes you could run that query in SSMS while your other one is running. Once you have it in SSMS, you can click on the XML and it will load it up. You should see pretty quickly whether it's the right one. Please share it via the link above

Answer (score -1):

It will be much more performant to convert the search value to string in c# code and then compare that against the database value (compared to casting the values in database). Though this will work only if the string values in the database are generated with consistent format.

`var serialSearchValue = cmrSearchDeliverySerialNumber.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` and use that in LINQ query.

Comment: by default it is string ,why I should do it again?!

Comment: if both are strings, then your problem is not related to string vs number - just a lack of index most likely as other comments suggested.

Comment: u think I want to convert my field in linq to an integer ,what should I do?

Comment: As the question states: *this field cmrSearchDeliverySerialNumber is string*. @amirkian You certainly don't want to convert the database field to integer before filtering, that's guaranteed to kill performance. I suspect what happens here is an internal nvarchar/varchar conversion, which should be visible in the query plan.

Comment: @GertArnold I wantt to convert databse field to integer before filtering in the linq expression, in this case.

Comment: @amirkian That's not happening. The expression is translated into SQL.