# Issue while loading query results to gridview asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am populating a set of results in asp.net grid-view from a stored procedure.
That stored procedure is very huge and taking some time to return the results.
While executing that stored procedure its taking two minutes , but I am able to see the results in the SQL Server Editor.
But in grid-view it is not loading and I am getting time out error.

Can any one please suggest me the solution?

**Error Details:**

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. 
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: Where is your code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As You have not post your source code, i can suggest you to have a look here,

[Poor Performance with Sqlparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590103/poor-performance-with-sqlparameter/8590152#8590152)

[Timeout Expiry issues.<- Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation)

Apart from that, its always preferred to load the data you can see on the single page. Loading more then 200 records in a grid view is not preferable. It will obviously slow down your screen.

Load on demand is the approach you can look forward to load your grid view .
[Load On Demand GridView](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-on-demand-data-in-GridView-on-scroll-using-ASPNet-and-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the solutions. Anyway I fixed this issue , by increasing command time out time. It works :)

Thanks Again.